# Removing Partition in Hard Drive

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

My laptop hard drive is divided 50/50 between Ubuntu and Mint. I want to remove the partition,remove Mint and free up the space for Ubuntu. How do I do this without destroying the data that I currently have on the Ubuntu side of the hard drive. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is your Ubuntu installation in the first partition (or just before the Mint)?

Comment: Which system's grub is installed to MBR. Usually last installed, unless you changed it. And you need to make sure you have the grub from the install you want to keep in the MBR as the one you use to boot. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Boot the computer from Ubuntu.

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

You must determine whether your system was booted in EFI or in BIOS mode.

Run it:

```
sudo ls /sys/firmware
```

If the system was booted off of EFI, the `/sys/firmware/efi` directory exist, like this:

```
acpi  memmap efi
```

If the `/sys/firmware/efi` directory does not appear, it was booted off of BIOS.

If your system was booted in EFI mode continue running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi
```

If your system was booted in BIOS mode continue running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub-common grub2-common
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
```

Once reinstalled Ubuntu Grub, load gparted running:

```
sudo gparted
```

Delete the Mint partition using GParted, create a new partition ext4 file system in free space, close it and continue running:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Boot the computer and mount the partition where suits you, /media/data, /home/user/data, /home/user/documents, etc.

Give permission to work on it:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

To create a mount point /media/data and give permission run:

```
sudo mkdir /media/data
sudo chmod -Rf 777 /media/data
```

To mount the partition permanently run:

```
sudo fdisk-l #To know how is called the partition, say it /dev/sda5
sudo blkid # To know how is UUID of the partition
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

In te open file paste de following:

```
#/media/data was on /dev/sda5
UUID=what_reported_blkid /media/data ext4    defaults        0       2
```

Change the data for their own, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.